# matplotlib: make plus sign thicker

Tags: python, matplotlib, markers

In Matplotlib, I would like to draw a **thick plus sign** (or a cross), but the one provided in the [marker set](http://www.loria.fr/~rougier/teaching/matplotlib/#markers) is too **thin**.

Even as I increase its size, it doesn't get any thicker.

For [example](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.boxplots.beanplot.html):
[image]
The [lines of code](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/_modules/statsmodels/graphics/boxplots.html) drawing the red plus sign are:

```
# Draw median marker.
if plot_opts.get('bean_show_median', True):
    ax.plot(pos, np.median(pos_data),
            marker=plot_opts.get('bean_median_marker', '+'),
            color=plot_opts.get('bean_median_color', 'r'))
```

If I add an extra parameter `markersize=20`, the marker will only stretch. It will be as thin as before. Can I make it thick?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use `markeredgewidth` (or `mew`). You'll want to combine it with `markersize`, otherwise you get thick but tiny markers.

For example:

```
plt.plot([2,4,6,1,3,5], '+', mew=10, ms=20)
```

[image]

Comment: For reference, it is useful to know that by default, `mew=0.5` and `ms=6` ... http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Answer (score 13):

Use [`markeredgewidth`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markeredgewidth) in connection with `markersize`.