# Adding a crosshair or marker to a matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm plotting a NumPy array as a contour plot using matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.contour(array, linewidths = 1, colors = 'k')
plt.contourf(array, cmap = plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I would like to add a 'crosshair' or another marker to denote the maximum value in the array which is given by:

```
maxi = np.max(array)
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: You can just plot at that point using the marker of your choice or you an use `axvline` and `axhlin` to create crossed lines that go to the edges of the axes.

Comment: @tcaswell I am not familiar with the syntax (and cant find it for some reason). Do you know or have a link?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply plot the cross if you know the position.

```
[row, col] = numpy.where(array==np.max(array))
plt.plot(col, row, 'b+')
```

To change the markersize [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172565/matplotlib-make-plus-sign-thicker).

Comment: great, now how to add the vertical and horizontal line to this point

Answer (score 0):

I added code to show a cross hair for the b+ marker using 6 increments for the xs and ys vertical and horizontal lines

```
b1=1.8027335249990852
xs=[4]*6
ys=np.linspace(0,int(4*b1),6)
ys2=[int(4*b1)]*6
xs2=np.linspace(0,4,6)

plt.plot(xs, ys,'k-', linestyle = ":", lw=1)
plt.plot(xs2, ys2,'k-', linestyle = ":", lw=1)
plt.plot(4, 4*b1, 'b+')
plt.show()
```