# Marker colour still not showing up

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The markers produced by the following are just showing up as grey:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax1.scatter(x
            , y
            , edgecolor='black'
            , color='black'
            , marker='x'
            , label='Cluster 1')
```

Comment: If I change the marker it looks pretty black to me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xEJB2.png. Using `marker='x'` I can't really distinguish grey from black.

Comment: Can you show your resulting figure?

Comment: @Bart this behaviour is only happening with marker='x' if I use marker='o' it is fine. But I'd like to use 'x' do I need to just change the weight of the marker line? If so, how?

Comment: No idea if that's possible. `plot()` has a `markeredgewidth` property (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22172981/3581217), but that doesn't seem to be the case for `scatter()`.

Comment: Ah, the property `linewidths` in `scatter()` seems to do the job

Comment: @Bart you can add it as the answer if you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marker probably looked grey because of the small line width, which can be controlled with the `linewidths` property:

```
plt.scatter(1, 1, s=300, edgecolor='black', 
            color='black', marker='x')
plt.scatter(2, 2, s=300, edgecolor='black', 
            color='black', marker='x', linewidths=2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this - maybe this question is something more interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417686/complex-pivot-and-resample