# Complex pivot and resample

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure where to start with this so apologies for my lack of an attempt.

This is the initial shape of my data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year-Mth': ['1900-01'
                 ,'1901-02'
                 ,'1903-02'
                 ,'1903-03'
                 ,'1903-04'
                 ,'1911-08'
                 ,'1911-09'], 
    'Category': ['A','A','B','B','B','B','B'], 
    'SubCategory': ['X','Y','Y','Y','Z','Q','Y'], 
    'counter': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
})

df
```

This is the result I'd like to get to - the Mth-Year in the below has been resampled to 4 year buckets:

[image]

If possible I'd like to do this via a process that makes 'Year-Mth' resamplable - so I can easily switch to different buckets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cols = [df.SubCategory, pd.to_datetime(df['Year-Mth']), df.Category]
df1 = df.set_index(cols).counter

df1.unstack('Year-Mth').T.resample('60M', how='sum').stack(0).swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index().fillna('')
```

[image]

Comment: Compared to ayhan's answer, let's call this approach  "rubikscubing your dataframe"

Comment: why the 60M? is that the same as using 5A, or would the other code need amending in order to use 5A?

Comment: Honest answer... I saw @ayhan posted his answer already and I thought to myself "you better hurry up now!" and then I forgot what the yearly string was, I tried "5Y", that failed.  I asked myself "should I look it up or just use '60M'"... and you know what I concluded.

Comment: pandas is an elegant thing - I need to keep playing and try to level-up !

Comment: actually when I try running this line `df1.unstack('Year-Mth').T.resample('60M').sum().stack(0).swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index().fillna('')` I get an error "series has no stack"

Comment: @whytheq what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @piRSquared 3.5 (via a jupyter notebook ... < this might be the important bit)

Comment: That's your Python version.  I want pd.__version__

Comment: @piRSquared 0.17.1

Comment: Try `df1.unstack('Year-Mth').T.resample('60M', method='sum').stack(0).swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index().fillna('')`

Comment: @piRSquared how='sum' does the job

Answer (score 5):

Here's my attempt:

```
df['Year'] = pd.cut(df['Year-Mth'].str[:4].astype(int), 
                    bins=np.arange(1900, 1920, 5), right=False)
df.pivot_table(index=['SubCategory', 'Year'], columns='Category', 
               values='counter', aggfunc='sum').dropna(how='all').fillna(0)
Out: 
Category                    A    B
SubCategory Year                  
Q           [1910, 1915)  0.0  1.0
X           [1900, 1905)  1.0  0.0
Y           [1900, 1905)  1.0  2.0
            [1910, 1915)  0.0  1.0
Z           [1900, 1905)  0.0  1.0
```

The year column is not parameterized as pandas (or numpy) does not offer a cut option with step size, as far as I know. But I think it can be done with a little arithmetic on minimums/maximums. Something like:

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year-Mth']).dt.year
df['Year'] = pd.cut(df['Year'], bins=np.arange(df['Year'].min(), 
                    df['Year'].max() + 5, 5), right=False)
```

This wouldn't create nice bins like Excel does, though.

Comment: thanks for this answer - as you mention this doesn't create nice bins like xl - but if you get the data into a for where it is possible to use the resample function then I think it is more powerful than xl.

Comment: Yeah but resample and similar methods are generally used with groupby. I don't know if that's possible with pivot_table. Similar to piRSquared's approach, you can use `df.groupby(['SubCategory', pd.Grouper(key='Year', freq='5A'), 'Category'])['counter'].sum().unstack('Category').fillna(0)` where 'Year' is a datetime type column (`df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year-Mth'])`).