# Is there anything in matplotlib that behaves like alpha but reversed?

Tags: python, matplotlib

A good way to show the concentration of the data points in a plot is using a scatter plot with non-unit transparency. As a result, the areas with more concentration would appear darker.

```
# this is synthetic example
N = 10000       # a very very large number
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='.', alpha=0.1)  # an area full of dots, darker wherever the number of dots is more
```

which gives something like this:

[image]

Imagine the case we want to emphasize on the outliers. So the situation is almost reversed: A plot in which the less-concentrated areas are bolder. (There might be a trick to apply for my simple example, but imagine a general case where a distribution of points are not known prior, or it's difficult to define a rule for transparency/weight on color.)

I was thinking if there's anything handy same as `alpha` that is designed for this job specifically. Although other ideas for emphasizing on outliers are also welcomed.

---

**UPDATE:** This is what happens when more then one data point is scattered on the same area:
[image]

I'm looking for something like the picture below, the more data point, the less transparent the marker.

[image]

Comment: what about using a slightly bigger marker? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172565/matplotlib-make-plus-sign-thicker

Comment: Use pcolor or pcolormesh, which will inherently convey the information about cell density.

Comment: @cmaureir After your comment, I added a little piece of code that clarifies the situation. In that case, the big marker would fill up the whole plot and the outliers would barely be visible.

Comment: @arash So what's the trouble with my solution? It produces exactly the bahvior you  posted in the extension of your question. Take a look at the edit in my answer for a reproduction of your example

Comment: Also have a look at https://github.com/astrofrog/mpl-scatter-density which I think has a way to use and image/mesh for dense regions and points in the spare regions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question: You can calculate the density of points, normalize it and encode it in the alpha channel of a colormap.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# this is synthetic example
N = 10000       # a very very large number
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)


fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8,5))
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='.', alpha=0.1)

values = np.vstack([x,y])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
weights = kernel(values)
weights = weights/weights.max()

cols = plt.cm.Blues([0.8, 0.5])
cols[:,3] = [1., 0.005]
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", cols)

ax2.scatter(x, y, c=weights, s = 1, marker='.', cmap=cmap)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Left is the original image, right is the image where higher density points have a lower alpha.

Note, however, that this is undesireable, because high density transparent points are undistinguishable from low density. I.e. in the right image it really looks as though you have a hole in the middle of your distribution.

Clearly, a solution with a colormap which does not contain the color of the background is a lot less confusing to the reader.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# this is synthetic example
N = 10000       # a very very large number
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

values = np.vstack([x,y])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
weights = kernel(values)
weights = weights/weights.max()

ax.scatter(x, y, c = weights, s=9, edgecolor="none", marker='.', cmap="magma")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here, low density points are still emphazised by darker color, but at the same time it's clear to the viewer that the highest density lies in the middle.

Comment: That's a nice and creative one. I totally agree that here in my example it pretty much delivers my intention. Yet, using a Gaussian kernel (especially w/o providing `bw_method`) might end up with misleading plots (imagine the cases in which not even we don't know the distribution, we don't know the typical size of the clusters).

I strongly believe that an internal function that handles colors in `matplotlib` is the best way. Since it both adds flexibility to the package and more importantly, it prevents extra computation.

Comment: Not sure what "an internal function" means here. Of course you can use other density estimates, `statsmodels` provides more flexibility than `scipy` in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no "direct" solution to this quite interesting problem. As a workaround, I propose this solution:

```
N = 10000       # a very very large number
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
fig = plt.figure()  # create figure directly to be able to extract the bg color
ax = fig.gca()
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='.')  # plot all markers without alpha
bgcolor = ax.get_facecolor()  # extract current background color
# plot with alpha, "overwriting" dense points
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='.', color=bgcolor, alpha=0.2)
```

This will plot all points without transparency and then plot all points again with some transparency, "overwriting" those points with the highest density the most. Setting the `alpha` value to other higher values will put more emphasis to outliers and vice versa.

Of course the color of the second scatter plot needs to be adjusted to your background color. In my example this is done by extracting the background color and setting it as the new scatter plot's color.

This solution is **independent of the kind of distribution**. It only depends on the density of the points. However it produces twice the amount of points, thus may take slightly longer to render.

---

Reproducing the edit in the question, my solution is showing exactly the desired behavior. The leftmost point is a single point and is the darkest, the rightmost is consisting of three points and is the lightest color.

```
x = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
fig = plt.figure()  # create figure directly to be able to extract the bg color
ax = fig.gca()
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='.', s=10000)  # plot all markers without alpha
bgcolor = ax.get_facecolor()  # extract current background color
# plot with alpha, "overwriting" dense points
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='.', color=bgcolor, alpha=0.2, s=10000)
```

Comment: That's a nice trick! Although, as you stated, it will double the rendering time and I'm not sure if it remains a feasible solution for cases with too many data points. Yet I believe it's one of the most general possible solutions as long as `matplotlib` doesn't provides this ability to the package.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, rendering time is a drawback. But for 2e6 points, it is about 4 seconds on my machine at fully vectorized output. So imho it is still acceptable. Since this is a question which is probably rarely sought after, I don't think matplotlib will include anything like this soon. On the other hand I found this question to be really interesting. I'm woring with regression and machine learning alot and I can already see thousands of applications. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming that the distributions are centered around a specific point (e.g. (0,0) in this case), I would use this:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 500
# 0 mean, 0.2 std
x = np.random.normal(0,0.2,N)
y = np.random.normal(0,0.2,N)

# calculate the distance to (0, 0).
color = np.sqrt((x-0)**2 + (y-0)**2)

plt.scatter(x , y, c=color, cmap='plasma', alpha=0.7)
plt.show()
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps you, because it's not exactly you asked for, but you can simply color points, which values are bigger than some threshold. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num = 100
threshold = 80

x = np.linspace(0, 100, num=num)
y = np.random.normal(size=num)*45

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.scatter(x[np.abs(y) < threshold], y[np.abs(y) < threshold], color="#00FFAA")
ax.scatter(x[np.abs(y) >= threshold], y[np.abs(y) >= threshold], color="#AA00FF")
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's not applicable to all the cases, unfortunately. You usually don't know the threshold. Plus, the distribution concentration might not be an easy function of the `x` and `y`.

Comment: Yeah, if the distribution is different, then this solution is wrong. But if the distribution is simple (like on the graph produced by my code), you can define the threshold as 80% of max value (or 1,5x median). This would broaden the usage of this code.